# Is localization of finite algebra also finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $A \to B$ a finite algebra, i.e., $B$ is finitely generated as $A$-module. If $S \subseteq B$ is a multiplicative subset, then $S^{-1}B$ is also finite $A$-algebra?

If not, how about $A=K$ a field and $S=\{1,b,b^2,\cdots\}$ for some $ 0 \neq b \in B$?

(In this special case I guess it is true and ask for making sure.)

In fact, I wanted to show the following:

Let $K$ be a field, $I \subseteq K[x]$ a nonzero ideal(so that $K[x]/I$ is finite dimensional), and $0 \neq b\in K[x]/I$ be a nonzero element. Then $(K[x]/I)[b^{-1}]$ is also finite dimensional.

Is general case true?

Can anyone comment?

Comment: How about $A=\mathbb{Z}=B$, $S=\mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}$ (or any nontrivial $S$ really)?

Comment: Yes. It has a simple counter example. $Q$ cannot be finitely generated $Z$-module, as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076387/bbbq-is-not-a-finitely-generated-bbbz-module. But the special cases can be true. Thanks for comment Mindlack :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this seldom happens. Let $B$ be a finite $A$-algebra and $b\in B$. If $x_1,\dotsc,x_n\in B$ generate $B$ as an $A$-module and $B[1/b]$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, then there is a $d\ge0$, such that $x_1,\dotsc,x_n,\frac{x_1}{b},\dotsc,\frac{x_n}{b},\dotsc,\frac{x_1}{b^d},\dotsc,\frac{x_n}{b^d}\in B[1/b]$ generate $B[1/b]$ as an $A$-module. That means there are $a_{ij}\in A$ for $i=1,\dotsc,n,\,j=0,\dotsc,d$, such that $$\frac{1}{b^{d+1}}=\sum_{j=0}^d\sum_{i=1}^na_{ij}\frac{x_i}{b^j}\qquad\text{ in $B[1/b]$}.$$
Setting $c=\sum_{j=0}^d\sum_{i=0}^na_{ij}x_ib^{d-j}\in B$, this implies that the image of $c$ under the canonical map $B\rightarrow B[1/b]$ is $1/b$. It follows that the canonical map $B\rightarrow B[1/b]$ is surjective. Conversely, if it surjective, $B[1/b]$ is obviously a finite $A$-algebra since $B$ is (the map is automatically $A$-linear, since it is a ring homomorphism). Note in particular that $B[1/b]$ is a finite $A$-algebra if and only if it is a finite $B$-algebra by these considerations, so there's no harm in assuming $A=B$ forthcoming. Let's analyze some special cases to see when this can happen.

If $B$ is an integral domain and $b\neq0$, the canonical map $B\rightarrow B[1/b]$ is always injective, so it is surjective if and only if it an isomorphism, which is the case if and only if $b\in B^{\times}$. So inverting something that is neither zero nor a unit always takes you out of the finite world.

If $B$ is a zero-dimensional local ring, every element of $B$ is either nilpotent or a unit. In the first case, $B[1/b]=0$, so $B\rightarrow B[1/b]=0$ is surjective. In the second case, $B[1/b]=B$ and $B\rightarrow B[1/b]=B$ is the identity, so surjective as well.

Now, if $B\cong B_1\times\dotsc\times B_n$ decomposes as a finite product of rings and $b\in B$ corresponds to $(b_1,\dotsc,b_n)\in B_1\times\dotsc\times B_n$, then we obtain a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
B @>{\sim}>> B_1\times\dotsc\times B_n\\
@VVV @VVV\\
B[1/b] @>{\sim}>> B_1[1/b_1]\times\dotsc\times B_n[1/b_n]
\end{CD},$$
where the vertical maps come from the canonical maps. It follows that the canonical map $B\rightarrow B[1/b]$ is surjective if and only if each of the canonical maps $B_i\rightarrow B_i[1/b_i]$ is surjective for $i=1,\dotsc,n$. Let's use this to generalize the previous two cases.

If $B$ is isomorphic to a finite direct product of integral domains $B_1\times\dotsc\times B_n$ and $b\in B$ corresponds to $(b_1,\dotsc,b_n)\in B_1\times\dotsc\times B_n$, the map $B\rightarrow B[1/b]$ is surjective if and only if $b_i=0$ or $b_i\in B_i^{\times}$ for each $i=1,\dotsc,n$. As an exercise, you can see that this is equivalent to the existence of a non-zero-divisor $c\in B$, such that $bc$ is idempotent.

If $B$ is zero-dimensional and has finite spectrum, then $B$ is canonically isomorphic to the product of its localizations, i.e. it is isomorphic to a finite product of zero-dimensional local rings. The previous observations combined imply that the canonical map $B\rightarrow B[1/b]$ is always surjective in this case. This applies in particular to Artinian rings such as non-trivial quotients of Dedekind domains. Specifically, it also implies to $B=K[X]/I$ for $K$ a field and $0\neq I\subseteq K[X]$ a non-trivial ideal, since $K[X]$ is a PID.

Comment: Yes. There can be various case that finiteness of $B[b^{-1}] cannot be true anymore. You present explanation until range that I cannot think. Thanks for argument in furthur detail.

Comment: And can I ask some question? 1) You wrote, "so the canonical maps $B→B[1/b]$ for each factor are either the identity or the unique map onto the trivial ring and surjective in either case. " What this statement exactly means? What "canonical maps for each factor" means?

Comment: I've made an edit that hopefully makes it clearer how I intended to deal with products.

Comment: Yes. Things becomes more clearer.  Exploration of various possible roots and exciting exposition. Helpful answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ is a finite dimensional $K$-algebra and $b\in B$ then let $g\in K[x]$ be its minimal polynomial, write $g  = x^r f\in K[x]$ with $f(0)\ne 0$, show that $f(b)\in \ker(B\to B[b^{-1}])$ and that $b\in B/(f(b))^\times$, whence $B[b^{-1}]=B/(f(b))$ and  $\dim_K S^{-1} B\le \dim_K B$.

Comment: Thanks. Through brutal force(?), it seems to have been seen that $b+(f(b)) \in  (B/(f(b)))^{\times}$ and $B[b^{-1}] = B /(f(b))$. Perhaps..is there any simple route of proof by noting some point? (How can you consider such $f(x)$ satisfies such conditions? Is there natural flow?)

Comment: Sorry what is unclear to you? $f(b)=0$ and $f = f(0) (1- xh)$ gives that $h(b)b=1$ ie. $b$ is a unit

Comment: O.K. Such a simple argument. And you said that "$b$ is a unit.". This means that $b$ is unit in '$B$'? It's different from "$b+(f(b))$ is unit in  $B/(f(b))$". Anyway, if $b$ is unit in $B$, then $b+(f(b))$ is also unit. I showed that directly. And we can show that $(f(b))=\operatorname{ker}(B \to B[b^{-1}])$. This refers to the 'brutal force' I wrote.

Comment: And  the map $B \to B[b^{-1}]$ is really surjecive? Since $b$ is unit of $B$? I am thinking that the unitness of $b$ in $B$ is used here.

Comment: $b$ is a unit in $B/(f(b))$ not in $B$

Comment: Some confusion. Above $h(b)$ is an element of $B$?(true?) If so, $h(b)$ is a multiplicative inverse of $b$ in $B$?

Comment: Anyway, let me make up your argument. First. We can show that $b +(f(b)) \in  B/(f(b))^{\times}$. So $B/(f(b)) \cong B/(f(b))[(b+(f(b)))^{-1}]$.
   Second, we can show that $(f(b)) = \operatorname{ker} \psi$, where $\psi : B \to B[b^{-1}]$.
   Third, we can show that $B[b^{-1}] \cong B/\operatorname{ker}[(b+\operatorname{ker})^{-1}]$ and we are done.